# Box size depending on input

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm starting to selfteach myself about HTML, CSS and JS. I'm trying to get a box sized depending on input fields.
Specifically said, I have 2 input fields (Heigth and Width). Depending on the value inserted in those fields a Div-Box should be displayed and change the size according to the values from the input fields. I believe that this can be done through JS, as starter I just have no idea how to do this.

```css
.boxA {
  width= ID=('width');
  height= ID=('height');
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<label for="height">Height</label>
  <input type="number" min="1" max="100" id="height" value="50"    step=".1">
<label for="width">Width</label>
  <input type="number" min="1" max="200" id="width" value="100" step=".1"></p>
  
<div class=boxA>Box A<div>
```

I know that the code wont work like that, just trying to show what I trying to achieve. Does anybody know how to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dimensions of a box are set through it's style, in other words CSS.

So you will need to

- Listen to changes of the value in your inputs
- Update the box's style attribute, specifically the width and height properties

Dimensions are changed by means of `element.style.width` and `element.style.height` properties. These properties are strings and require a unit, so you'll need to add f.e. 'px'.

You can listen to changes of values by binding a listener (`addEventListener`) to the [input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event).

```js
const boxA = document.getElementById("boxA");

document.getElementById("height").addEventListener("input", e => {
  boxA.style.height = e.target.value + "px";
});
document.getElementById("width").addEventListener("input", e => {
  boxA.style.width = e.target.value + "px";
});
```

```css
.boxA {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<label for="height">Height</label>
<input type="number" min="1" max="100" id="height" value="50" step=".1">
<label for="width">Width</label>
<input type="number" min="1" max="200" id="width" value="100" step=".1"></p>

<div id="boxA" class=boxA>Box A
  <div>
```

Comment: This is great thanks, works easier then I thought. I have a question to add to this. If I have the lenght in inches and want to change them to cm I normall do this by creating a new var like sumWidth = width.valueAsNumber * 2.54; -> sumWidth = sumWidth.ToFixed(0); -> How do I add this into the value or how do I change it or is that approch to complicated?

Comment: `e.target.value` is the value from the input (inside the eventHandler). You would only need to change the line to `boxA.style.width = e.target.value * 2.54 + "cm"` if you want to assign the style property in cm. Be aware though, the CSS unit cm does not at all correspond to a cm on your screen. Browsers always convert to px in the end, [see CSS length units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#Lengths)

Comment: oh thank you ver much. I'm aware that cm does not exist as value for the screen. I just want to show difference between floorsizes for hamster cages. the german standard for floor space is for example 100x50cm. so I want to display a box with the size of 100px x 50px. Then if an american user inserts his floor space in inches I need to translat it into cm so it can be correctly compared for the users that uses inches instead of cm.